# QGIS time manager not processing date info correctly (points not drawn)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, timemanager

I'm trying to visualize some temporal data with the QGIS time manager plugin. Therefore, I

1. loaded a .`kml`-file into QGIS as a new layer (which gets displayed correctly).
2. Then I also added this layer to the Time Manager plugin where I set the info `timestamp` as the `Start time` to be used, and fruthermore set `No end time - accumulate features` as `End time`.

When I now want to play the visualization, the info shown in `Time frame start` seems to be correct, but no points are drawn to the map.

My `.kml`-file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":Metadata>
    <Document>
        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <when>2018-05-24</when>
            </TimeStamp>
            <name>one</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>88.550000000000011,50.087537</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <when>2018-05-12</when>
            </TimeStamp>
            <name>two</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>12.410425,51.380772</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <when>2018-05-07</when>
            </TimeStamp>
            <name>three</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>6.774438,51.250303</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <when>2018-05-06</when>
            </TimeStamp>
            <name>four</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>11.070093,49.448922</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <when>2018-05-05</when>
            </TimeStamp>
            <name>five</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>8.752525,51.772846</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <when>2018-01-04</when>
            </TimeStamp>
            <name>six</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>13.386048,52.574590</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <when>2018-01-03</when>
            </TimeStamp>
            <name>seven</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>9.211243,48.768894</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <when>2017-11-02</when>
            </TimeStamp>
            <name>eight</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>12.410425,51.380772</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <when>2017-11-01</when>
            </TimeStamp>
            <name>nine</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>11.070093,49.448922</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <when>2017-10-30</when>
            </TimeStamp>
            <name>ten</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>13.386048,52.574590</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <when>2017-10-26</when>
            </TimeStamp>
            <name>eleven</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>8.550000000000011,50.087537</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <when>2017-10-25</when>
            </TimeStamp>
            <name>twelve</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>8.752525,51.772846</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is not working?

Comment: Your KML is invalid `cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":name}'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":styleUrl, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":AbstractStyleSelectorGroup, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":Region, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":Metadata, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":ExtendedData, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":AbstractFeatureSimpleExtensionGroup, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":AbstractFeatureObjectExtensionGroup, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":AbstractGeometryGroup, ...' is expected.`

Comment: I changed it with all of the above suggestions, but I still have the same problem. Does it work for you?

Comment: Could you edit the question to provide your valid KML

Comment: Done (I added Metadata to the question). Thanks for helping me with this...

Comment: Sorry, it's still not valid.  How are you creating and validating the KML?

Comment: Something like:  `<Placemark>
            <name>one</name>
            <TimeStamp>
                <when>2018-05-24</when>
            </TimeStamp>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>88.550000000000011,50.087537</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>...` perhaps.